# How to send 0 in protobuf repeated field?

Tags: arrays, list, networking, null, protocol-buffers

For example when I try to send an array with these values [14,56,0,63,22,6], my client receives only
the values before the zero [14,56]. I know that the default values are not serialized, but this 0 is in repeated field. So is it possible to send the whole array over the wire with protobuf message?

```
syntax = "proto3";

package server;

message SrvPossibleMoves {
  int32 id = 1;
  int32 index = 2;
  repeated int32 moves = 3 [packed=false];
}
```

Comment: Which library / platform are you using? Are you sure you don't have anything in your processing that treats it as a c-style string (i.e. nul-terminated) - as the zero value will appear as a literal zero byte, which would cause nul-terminated handlers to stop processing, but: protobuf libraries know not to do that

Comment: You were absolutely right. My client treats the buffer as a char array and here it comes the problem. Exactly on this line of code: "std::strlen(data_.get())". Thank you very much, it is already fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(expanded version of a inquiry in the comments)

This sounds typical of a problem with intermediate code (not the protobuf library itself, but something when passing around the bytes) is treating the payload as a C-style (nul-terminated) string. The zero value in this scenario will be encoded as a zero byte, which is perfectly valid in binary data, but which will cause C-style string handling APIs to cut the data at that point. I would *expect* most protobuf libraries to detect that it was expecting additional values (there are some scenarios where this is possible, and some where it isn't possible; in this case - it seems possible), and throw an exception at this point, but... that would be library-specific.

So: check the code for C-style string handling, and remove any such - typically by passing the length and payload in unison (instead of relying on a terminator).

---

In this case, the offending code was: `std::strlen(data_.get())`.

Answer (score 1):

> So is it possible to send the whole array over the wire with protobuf message?

Yes: there is absolutely no special meaning for 0 as a value in a repeated field. You can send 5 0s, or 20, or 201 -- it makes absolutely no difference.

> my client receives only the values before the zero

Something is very wrong. Most likely there is a bug in your client (or possibly in your server).